# Regular expression to find block

Tags: php, html, regex

I need your help with regular expression.
Here is a sample html i would like to run your provided regular expression:

```
<div id="divId">
    {% block var_name1 %}
      <p> Hello world </p>
    {% endblock %}
    <div class="someclass">
       {% block var_name2 %}
         <span>Hello span</span>
       {% endblock %}
    </div> 
</div>
```

And find all matching block like **preg_match_all** does in php :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
   array(2) {
    [0]=>  "var_name1"
    [1]=>  "var_name2"
   }
  [1]=>
   array(2) {
    [0]=>  "<p> Hello world </p>"
    [1]=>  "<span>Hello span</span>"
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work

```
/\{% block (.+?) %\}(.*?)\{% endblock %\}/ims
```

`(.+?)` means group of any characters, at least one but ungreedy (`?`). If you have more specific requirements you have to change it.

It's straight forward and very strict. So more than one space between `%` and `block` let the regex crash.

To be more obliging:

```
/\{%\s+block\s+(.+?)\s+%\}(.*?)\{%\s+endblock\s+%\}/ims
```

`\s+` means at least one char like space or tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression you are looking for:

```
preg_match_all('/\{% block ([a-z0-9_]+) %\}(.*?)\{% endblock %\}/is', $text)
```

Comment: I would write `([a-z0-9_]+)` cause it's very likely that there has to be at least one or more chars. Your regex also works for `{% block  }...{% endblock %}`

Comment: You're right, I edit it.